# Integrated luminosity in a Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: particle-physics, higgs, large-hadron-collider

Suppose we have a Monte Carlo simulation comprising momenta values. How do we calculate the integrated luminosity? There is no time and all values are discrete so I don't understand how I should integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

Simulation is a way to model a certain physics process. One can generate as many events of this process ($N_{signal}$) as it is needed. Knowing the number of events in your given sample, and the cross-section of this process (either theoretical or experimentally measured in the past) you can convert the number of events into the [integrated luminosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_(scattering_theory)) by simply doing $\mathcal{L} = N_{signal}/\sigma_{process}$. Note that if the process involves a decay of a particle A into a certain final state, you also need to take into account both production cross-section of the particle A and the branching fraction of its decay to this final state. In addition, detector imperfections lead to detection efficiency being lower than 1. Therefore, you need to know the number of generated events rather than the number of events reconstructed by the detector in your simulation.

However in reality, the concept of luminosity is rarely used when working with simulation, but rather used when describing the amount of experimental data.